# Why should I care about cancelling an ajax request in the browser?

Tags: javascript, ajax, react-redux, redux-saga

I've been building apps in React and Redux (though the issue would be true with Rx (Angular) or other frameworks) where we might fire off several coincidental ajax requests to fetch data for a particular page.  Imagine one page with 3 components each which want the User data.  Each one might, on mount, fire off an ajax request to get the customer data.

If under the hood we use `fetch`, there is no easy way to "cancel" the requests.  If we use `axios`, there is a built in way to "cancel" requests that may have gone out.

My question is - is there a good reason to try to cancel those requests?  In reading I know there can be race conditions and other issues.  But if we've worked around that (using sagas and `takeLatest` which has it's own "cancel" mechanism), is there a compelling reason to cancel ajax requests that are outstanding and would otherwise be dropped on the floor?

Comment: While it's generally considered "cleaner" to cancel ones that you don't need, there's no issue just letting them fail. Assuming you have, as you've said, made sure that that won't cause any bugs or issues

Comment: I can say a example: if a user is waiting for a page load and got tired he can simple cancel and go to another page/make another thing; and under the hood you can cancel the pending requests. The behavior of canceling a long running task (thread or i/o) is present on almost api's

Comment: Another example is using a keep alive fetch to pull information from server (instead of using a websocket), you can cancel the requests when this information is no more needed.